# Dr. Watson alternatives for Windows 2008+?

Tags: debugging, windows-server-2008, drwatson

We used to use Dr. Watson logfiles and dumps for crash analysis in our production environment, but Dr. Watson is no longer part of server 2k8 and our infrastructure team has had issues getting it running on 2008.

Are there alternatives that can be used in a similar way?  In particular, we'd need the faulting module and address causing the crash (we use this with the PDB and map information to backtrace to the faulting location), and it would have to work with windows services (including those running as localsystem).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure Windows Error Reporting to automatically save a dump file locally for you.  More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

We also have all our server cut off from the outside world. It is beter to collect the data yourself and sent it to Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how quickly you need to respond to these things, you can just let Microsoft do the collection for you.  You can get crash data from [WER](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/maintain/StartWER.mspx), you just have to sign up.

Comment: For client applications, this is great.  WER doesn't work quite as well in a server environment, which it looks like the question is about.

Comment: Many corporations don't allow the servers in their datacenter to make outbound connections, disabling the WER pipe.

For a single inhouse application in a production environment, WER is just overhead - why register, send data from a single application in a small pool of machines out of your environment to MS, then go to MS to retrieve them again and download them back to your environment?

Comment: Okay, that all seems reasonable.  I guess you just have to decide how lazy you want to be.  Because you could make it work fairly easily if you were so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/), which I gather does much the same thing.