# Invoking VS debugger on process crash vista-win8k

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, windows-7, windows-xp

On xp, every time a process would crash the OS would pop up a dialog asking if I would like to debug the process. I cant find a way to enable this functionality on the later version of windows. So to reiterate, I want to attach a debugger to a native process that's auto broken on a crash.

Does anyone know how to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enable Just-In-Time debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx).

Edit: since that doesn't work for you, some additional suggestions -

- Make sure the [AeDebug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) registry key values are correct.
- [Setup WER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) to create full crash dumps, and debug the dumps.
- Not sure about this, but is it possible your user doesn't have debug permissions? Have never checked that, but I assume this would prevent that user from being offered a chance to debug the process (and even if you do, UAC might circumvent them - but I don't know this for a fact).

Comment: Been enabled all along no dice

Comment: I think i narrowed down my problem, jit will not trigger on process starting under the service manager so if you need to debug something you will need to find a way to start it from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [Dr. Watson tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308538). [This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188296) explains how to disable or enable it.

Comment: The good old dr. is not part of Windows anymore. You won't find it on 2008, but [there are alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505831/dr-watson-alternatives-for-windows-2008).